GitLab CI/CD Tests Fail (Connection Errors) for Flask App Despite Success Locally
Body:
I am experiencing consistent issues with my GitLab CI/CD pipeline, where all types of tests (stress, functional, and e2e) consistently fail when executed in the pipeline but pass without any problems when run locally. Below, I've detailed the setup, errors, and various troubleshooting steps I've already attempted.
Environment:

Flask App running locally on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Tests: Using Locust for stress tests, Cypress for functional tests, and Maven for e2e tests
CI/CD: GitLab using dockerized environments for each test

Errors:
- Stress Tests: All requests to the Flask app's API endpoints in stress tests return
-ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused').
18575              GET /api/company-details/[ticker]: ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused') 

- Functional Tests (Cypress): The error occurs during the parsing of arguments with an unexpected script being executed instead of JSON configuration.
(Cypress encountered an error while parsing the argument: --config)

- E2E Tests (Maven): Compilation failure due to an invalid target release.
([ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project untitled: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 21 -> [Help 1])

.gitlab-ci.yml (simplified for clarity):
image: python:3.9

stages:
  - test
  - deploy

before_script:
  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y maven
  - python -m venv venv
  - source venv/bin/activate
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - export PYTHONPATH=./src

stress_tests:
  script:
    - locust -f src/tests/stress/company_stress_test.py --headless --host http://127.0.0.1:5000

functional_tests:
  image: cypress/included:10.0.0
  script:
    - npx cypress run --config-file src/tests/functional/cypress.config.js

e2e_tests:
  script:
    - cd src/tests/e2e
    - mvn test

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
Confirmed all tests pass locally.
Ensured paths and environment variables are correctly set in CI configurations.
Attempted using different Docker images and configurations for the tests.
Questions:

How can I resolve the connection issues in the GitLab CI environment for stress tests?

What might be causing the argument parsing error with Cypress in the GitLab CI environment?

How can I fix the Maven target release error in the e2e tests?

Could the use of multiple Docker images in the GitLab CI pipeline be complicating the networking between containers? If so, how can I configure the CI to handle this properly?


Additional Concerns:
I'm also wondering if the issues might stem from the complexity of managing multiple Docker images within the same pipeline. Each type of test uses a different base image, which could potentially lead to network isolation or misconfiguration issues between these containers:

Stress tests are run without a specific image: declaration, implying the use of the default Python image.
Functional tests use the cypress/included:10.0.0 image.
E2E tests revert to using the default Python image but also require Maven, which is installed in the before_script.
This setup requires inter-container communication, which might be improperly configured or blocked due to network isolation features inherent to Docker’s networking.

I am looking for any insights or suggestions on resolving these CI/CD pipeline issues. Thank you in advance for your help!

I don’t see in your ci file anywhere that you start your flask application. Does locust load up the flask app or just make the requests to the application expecting it to be live?
If so you will need to add in the flask start command to make sure it is listening at the right address before starting tests.
For Cypress config issue can you try the -C flag to see if it parses those correctly.
Using multiple images should be okay so long as you specify the required image in each job the gitlab runner should create the image and run the steps in that stage.
For the maven issue, depending on where the run environment is (locally hosted or gitlab cloud) you could spin up the containers on that machine and try to run the tests if it is locally hosted. Gitlab hosted will require adding in more debug related steps to make sure the right steps can be done to get it to work
Hope it helps :)
